# What time time do A and B meet?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, fundamental-solution

**A** starts from **X** at `9:00 am` and reaches **Y** at `1:00 pm`.
**B** starts from **Y** at `9:00 am` and reaches **X** at `3:00 pm`.

What time do the two meet?

So we can see that,

```
9am ----> 1pm is 4 hrs

9am ----> 3pm is 6 hrs
```

Now I am stuck how to assume the total distance then speed. With the concepts I know `Distance = Speed * Time`

How to find the combined speed if I at least assume the distance as 100?

If I am not wrong I have to consider calculating the relative speed.

Comment: What is the "combined" speed? There exists a time when both $A$ and $B$ are the same distance away from $X$ (or $Y$). Find that time. I assume the speeds are constant, otherwise there's not enough data to solve.

Comment: If $Distance = Speed * Time$, then $Speed = Distance/Time$. So you can easily find $Speed_A$ and $Speed_B$. They both start at the same time, 100 miles apart, and the speed at which they reduce that distance is $Speed_A+Speed_B$. Now you can use $Time=Distance/Speed.$.

Comment: I found in couple of google search that the distance is assumed as the LCM of 4 and 6, which is basically the time. So assumed distance is 12. Is that even proper assumption? @3rdMoment

Comment: If $X = 0$ then you have to have $Y = 100$.  The first guys first guy starts at $0$ and goes forward and used the formula Distance = speed * time, but the second guy starts at 100 and goes in the opposite direction.  Her distance formula must be subtracted from $100$.  Her formula is Distance = 100 -speed * time.

Comment: The answer doesn't depend on the distance, so you can choose any distance you want. I thought your idea to choose a concrete distance of 100 miles was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose speeds are constant and the distance between $X$ and $Y$ is $1$ unit. Then $v_A = 1/4$ and $v_B = 1/6$. The distance measured from $X$ is given by
$$ d_A = \frac{1}{4}t,\quad t\leqslant 4,\quad\mbox{and}\quad d_B = 1-\frac{1}{6}t,\quad t\leqslant 6. $$
For some $t_0\leqslant 4$, the two quantities are equal. Find $t_0$.

Comment: $dB=1−(1/6)t$ I think this would be just $(1/6)t$ if I am not wrong. But if I am, please explain... I am a 9th class student. Trying to practice some competitive questions.

Comment: @codeapplied at $t=0$, $B$ is $1$ unit away from $X$, not $0$. Do you agree?

Comment: A few concepts.  We aren't trying to find the *distance* traveled but the *location*.  The figure location you must take there starting locations into account.  So $d_A = 0 + \frac 14t$ because he started at $0$.  B is traveling in the opposite direction so we have to subtract her speed.  $d_B = 1 -\frac 16t$ because she started at $1$ and went back down to $0$.